# Console.SetOut does not work with ConsoleLogger

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

In my asp.net application, I'm using ConsoleLogger when debug.

```
services.AddLogging(builder => builder.AddConsole());
```

In integration tests, I'm trying to obtain console output like this

```
var strWriter = new StringWriter();
Console.SetOut(strWriter);

// some code that has a lot of logging

var consoleOutput = strWriter.ToString();
```

and consoleOutput is an empty string.

Is that issue with ConsoleLogger? How can I obtain console output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why you want to do this and even more - I would say you should not do this, at least this way, but if you still want - you will need `Console.SetOut` before writing first messages to log, i.e. in case of ASP.NET Core it should look something like this:

```
public static StringWriter GlobalStringWriter = new StringWriter(); // use this "singleton"
    
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.SetOut(GlobalStringWriter);
    CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
}
```

Note that it will capture all concurrent requests (as it should do anyway).

If you take a look at source code for [`ConsoleLoggerProvider`](https://source.dot.net/#Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console/ConsoleLoggerProvider.cs,11a5065faa49c41b) (which is actually setup with `AddConsole` call), you will see that in internally uses [`AnsiLogConsole`](https://source.dot.net/#Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console/AnsiLogConsole.cs,cf1475aeb3d1f94e)/[`AnsiParsingLogConsole`](https://source.dot.net/#Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console/AnsiParsingLogConsole.cs,b2faeac8361dc1dd) both of which internally capture current value of `System.Console.Error`/`System.Console.Out` in theirs constructors:

```
public AnsiParsingLogConsole(bool stdErr = false)
{
    _textWriter = stdErr ? System.Console.Error : System.Console.Out;
    _parser = new AnsiParser(WriteToConsole);
}

public AnsiLogConsole(bool stdErr = false)
{
    _textWriter = stdErr ? System.Console.Error : System.Console.Out;
}
```

So setting the string writer after this capture happened does not actually change where logs are written.

I would say that this is not very good approach and possibly you better think about implementing some kind of your own [logger provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/custom-logging-provider) which will allow you to handle this usecase, or use an existing one and set it up for debug mode to write to file.